# Hooking into WELD-SE classpath scanner

Tags: java, weld, weld-se

I've been looking for documentation on WELD-SE's classpath scanner API, but haven't been able to find any. I'm trying to discover POJOs with custom annotations in the spirit of the Servlet, WebSocket and JAX-RS APIs. Is there any way to do this with WELD?

I realize that there are already libraries that do classpath scanning, such as Scannotation, FastClasspathScanner, Corn-CPS, etc., but I'm trying to keep this project lean and don't mind tight integration with WELD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weld doesn't have any such API. The scanner Weld uses is not "general-enough" for this. It is rather CDI-specific as it focuses on discovering bean archives.

If the POJOs you are looking for are in fact CDI beans, you could simply write a CDI extension and observe `ProcessAnnotatedType<?>` phase which will notify you of all `AnnotatedType`s CDI picks up. This can be further narrowed down using `@WithAnnotations` to only select AT with given annotations.

In certain environments, Weld also allows to work with [Jandex](https://github.com/wildfly/jandex) which is something you could perhaps use as a different tool.